# How to have UniformGrid fill all its cells

Tags: wpf

I want to display my `ItemsControl` as a grid with 2 rows and 4 columns. I'm using `UniformGrid` and the best way I've found to get "Gridlines" is to give a border to each item in the `ItemTemplate` as well as a border around the entire `ItemsControl`.

```xml
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="10 20">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TemplatesList}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="4" Rows="2"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/> 
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Border>
```

However, when there are fewer than 8 items, the "unfilled" items slots are completely blank. I want to know if there's a way for the grid to always have the 8 cells all with their gridlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UniformGrid is just a layout panel, it doesn't "fill" its cells with anything unless you give it something to fill them with. The proper way to solve this would be to pad your TemplatesList out with null entries to make up the full 8, but if you don't want to do this then you just remove your ItemsSource binding and populate the ItemsControl with ContentPresenters directly. Of course, your output pane will now be flooded with exception warnings about trying to bind to elements outside the collection's range, so you'll have to use a converter to get rid of those.

To put it another way, do this:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="10 20">
    <ItemsControl VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ItemsControl.Resources>
            <local:ItemLookupConverter x:Key="ItemLookupConverter" />
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.Resources>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="4" Rows="2"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding TemplatesList, Converter={StaticResource ItemLookupConverter}, ConverterParameter=0}" />
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding TemplatesList, Converter={StaticResource ItemLookupConverter}, ConverterParameter=1}" />
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding TemplatesList, Converter={StaticResource ItemLookupConverter}, ConverterParameter=2}" />
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding TemplatesList, Converter={StaticResource ItemLookupConverter}, ConverterParameter=3}" />
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding TemplatesList, Converter={StaticResource ItemLookupConverter}, ConverterParameter=4}" />
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding TemplatesList, Converter={StaticResource ItemLookupConverter}, ConverterParameter=5}" />
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding TemplatesList, Converter={StaticResource ItemLookupConverter}, ConverterParameter=6}" />
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding TemplatesList, Converter={StaticResource ItemLookupConverter}, ConverterParameter=7}" />
    </ItemsControl>
</Border>
```

Here's the converter you'll need, I'll assume your TemplatesList supports IList:

```
public class ItemLookupConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var index = Int32.Parse(parameter.ToString());
        var collection = value as IList;
        return (index < collection.Count) ? collection[index] : null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```